# cannot change default rails error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, locale

I have the following validation for my Profile model:

```
validates :category, presence: true, 
  inclusion: {in: categories, message: "Please choose a category from the list."}
```

And the following in my en.yml file:

```
en:
  active_record:
    errors:
      models:
        profile:
          attributes:
            category:
              blank: "Category must be present."
```

Yet, for some reason, the error  message that is displayed is still the default:

```
can't be blank
```

how do I make the locale file work and change the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `en.yml` file you should be using `activerecord`, not `active_record`.

Comment: I know, i want separate messages for inclusion and presence.

Comment: But also, I have a lot more error messages I need to set up, and i want to figure out why the locale file is not working.

Comment: Oops sorry; just fixed my answer.

Comment: awesome,thanks, that almost fixed it.  Now it displays the "category must be presen" message and "can't be blank"